# flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderPointerListener object was given an infinite size during layout

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, flutter-layout

I have an issue with my Code... I dont know how I can fix that problem. I want to do a reoderableList but everytime I am drag and drop one task, the hole tasks in the ios simulation are changing into one task and flutter gives me that this error message.

> flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderPointerListener object was given an infinite size during layout.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:todoapp/models/classes/task.dart';
import 'package:todoapp/models/global.dart';
import 'package:todoapp/models/widgets/intray_todo_widget.dart';

class IntrayPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _IntrayPageState createState() => _IntrayPageState();
}

class _IntrayPageState extends State<IntrayPage> {
  List<Task> taskList = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    taskList = getList();
    return Container(
      color: darkGreyColor,
      child: _buildReorderableListSimple(context),
      // child: ReorderableListView(
      //   padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 300),
      //   children: todoItems,
      //   onReorder: _onReorder,
      // ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildListTile(BuildContext context, Task item) {
    return ListTile(
      key: Key(item.taskId),
      title: IntrayTodo(
        title: item.title,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildReorderableListSimple(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData(canvasColor: Colors.transparent),
      child: ReorderableListView(
        // handleSide: ReorderableListSimpleSide.Right,
        // handleIcon: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 300.0),
        children:
            taskList.map((Task item) => _buildListTile(context, item)).toList(),
        onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
          setState(() {
            Task item = taskList[oldIndex];
            taskList.remove(item);
            taskList.insert(newIndex, item);
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onReorder(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
    setState(() {
      if (newIndex > oldIndex) {
        newIndex -= 1;
      }
      final Task item = taskList.removeAt(oldIndex);
      taskList.insert(newIndex, item);
    });
  }

  List<Task> getList() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      taskList.add(Task("My first todo " + i.toString(), false, i.toString()));
    }
    return taskList;
  }
}
```

[Here is the error log, you can see there is some other error too "multiple widgets are using the same global key but I think thats an other problem for an other thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuJod.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing `taskList` inside the build method. It's called every time whenever you call `setState`. You have to initialize the taskList variable inside the `initState` method instead of build method. It will be called only once in the stateful widget life cycle. I resolved this issue by the following way.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    taskList = getList();
    super.initState();
  }
```

[For your reference, I have attached the gif image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjVQO.gif)